# Taking GET parameters as func arguments or using c.Params.Get() in Golang Revel

Tags: go, revel, http-parameters

In the [Golang Revel](https://revel.github.io/) web framework, what's the difference between setting function arguments as parameters (for both GET and POST)

```
func (c Machine) TestConnection(addr string, port int, username, password string) revel.Result
```

versus retrieving HTTP parameters from within the function

```
addr := c.Params.Get("addr")
port, _ := strconv.Atoi(c.Params.Get("port"))
username := c.Params.Get("username")
password := c.Params.Get("password")
```

---

Also, if I use the function arguments method (the first method), can I still validate the HTTP parameters with `c.Validation.Required("addr").Ok`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whichever you prefer. However, defining them as method parameters lets the framework take care of parsing the string from the request to the type that you need. So it's offered as convenience.

Comment: Alright, I'll switch my code to use function parameters instead. Thank you.

Comment: And about my second question at the end of my post?

Comment: If anything, validation is meant to work _with_ the method parameters.